# MATLAB plotting function similar to xyplot() from Lattice package

Tags: r, matlab, scatter-plot

I would like to know if there is any similar function to the `xyplot()` function from the lattice package in R. I would like to plot groups of observations classified by subgroups in different charts.

For example, if I have the following dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(ID=paste0("id",1:40),
       Group=paste0("group",rep(1:4,10)),
       Subgroup=paste0("subgroup",c(rep(c("A","B","B"),13),"A")),
       ValueX=rnorm(40),
       ValueY=rnorm(40))
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(d$ValueY ~ d$ValueX | d$Group, group=as.factor(d$Subgroup),
          auto.key=list(space="right", points=T), pch=20)
```

In MATLAB, I defined `d` as a dataset and plotted the following using `sbiotrellis` function:

```
sbiotrellis(d,'Group','ValueX','ValueY')
```

However, the subgroups are not being considered. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered `ggplot2`?  Or maybe you mean you want it in MATLAB only?  On re-read I can't tell.

Comment: It appeared to me that there was a mechanism in MATLAB plotting routines to merge plots as well as to specify groups in the 4th argument to `sbiotrellis`. Not having a MATLAB installation prevents me from doing any further investigation. I would have thought that presenting the data in a format that could be copy-pasted into a MATLAB session would garner more interest from folks that did have such access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**R:**

```
write.table(d, file = "myfile.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```

**Matlab:**

Operating System

```
lsb_release -i -r

     Distributor ID:    RedHatEnterpriseServer
     Release:   6.5
```

Matlab Version and Release

```
version -date

% ans =
%
% September 15, 2014

version -release

% ans =
%
% 2014b

version -java

%ans =
%
%Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

Data

```
ds = dataset('File', 'myfile.csv','Delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines', 1, 'ReadVarNames', false, 'ReadObsNames', true);
vn = {'ID', 'Group', 'Subgroup', 'ValueX', 'ValueY'};
ds = set(ds, 'VarNames', vn);

ds
% ds = 
% 
%             ID              Group             Subgroup             ValueX       ValueY    
%     "1"     '"id1"'         '"group1"'        '"subgroupA"'           0.5524      -0.21252
%     "2"     '"id2"'         '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.30546      -0.12646
%     "3"     '"id3"'         '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.96933       -1.0407
%     "4"     '"id4"'         '"group4"'        '"subgroupA"'         0.024616       -1.1806
%     "5"     '"id5"'         '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'           0.3268      -0.97485
%     "6"     '"id6"'         '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'          0.55165      -0.70415
%     "7"     '"id7"'         '"group3"'        '"subgroupA"'          0.36608      -0.97104
%     "8"     '"id8"'         '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'         0.028234       0.26336
%     "9"     '"id9"'         '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'          0.71088       0.97357
%     "10"    '"id10"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupA"'         -0.14237    -0.0085301
%     "11"    '"id11"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'           1.1259      -0.85614
%     "12"    '"id12"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'          0.73305       0.33118
%     "13"    '"id13"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupA"'          0.41297      -0.28922
%     "14"    '"id14"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.41621       0.35157
%     "15"    '"id15"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.48856       0.85537
%     "16"    '"id16"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupA"'          -1.8682        0.6652
%     "17"    '"id17"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'        -0.098612         1.563
%     "18"    '"id18"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.53824       0.57049
%     "19"    '"id19"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupA"'          0.24112         0.168
%     "20"    '"id20"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.35454         -1.23
%     "21"    '"id21"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.45688        1.2703
%     "22"    '"id22"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupA"'          0.68444       -1.3548
%     "23"    '"id23"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'          -1.1469        2.1724
%     "24"    '"id24"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'        -0.035062      -0.41989
%     "25"    '"id25"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupA"'          -1.2422        1.2415
%     "26"    '"id26"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'           2.1308      -0.76941
%     "27"    '"id27"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.87732       -0.9218
%     "28"    '"id28"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupA"'             2.14       0.12569
%     "29"    '"id29"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'          0.13455      -0.22301
%     "30"    '"id30"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'          -1.0742      -0.35052
%     "31"    '"id31"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupA"'           -1.121       0.55119
%     "32"    '"id32"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'          0.88677       -1.1549
%     "33"    '"id33"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.28575        1.1066
%     "34"    '"id34"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupA"'         -0.10857       -2.0048
%     "35"    '"id35"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.78056       0.23084
%     "36"    '"id36"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupB"'         -0.16794      -0.48823
%     "37"    '"id37"'        '"group1"'        '"subgroupA"'        -0.080923         0.309
%     "38"    '"id38"'        '"group2"'        '"subgroupB"'           1.7291       -1.0569
%     "39"    '"id39"'        '"group3"'        '"subgroupB"'          -1.2291       -1.7684
%     "40"    '"id40"'        '"group4"'        '"subgroupA"'          -1.3804        1.4364
```

Divide the data into groups based on Subgroup variable

```
target = 'subgroupA';
vi = find(cellfun('length', regexp(ds.Subgroup, target)) == 1);
data1 = ds(vi, :);

target = 'subgroupB';
vi = find(cellfun('length', regexp(ds.Subgroup, target)) == 1);
data2 = ds(vi, :);
```

Plot trellis plot. Use `hold on` to plot multiple layers on to one figure

```
t1 = sbiotrellis(data1, 'Group', 'ValueX', 'ValueY', 'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o', 'MarkerEdgeColor', [1,0,0], 'MarkerSize', 4, 'MarkerFaceColor', [1,0,0]);
hold on
t2 = sbiotrellis(data2, 'Group', 'ValueX', 'ValueY', 'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o', 'MarkerEdgeColor', [0,0,1], 'MarkerSize', 4, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0,0,1]);

t2.labelx = 'X';
t2.labely = 'Y';
t2.plottitle = 'My Trellis Plot';
```

Plot upto this point:

[image]

Capture gcf which gives the handle to the parent of the current figure

```
bx = gcf

%   bx = 
% 
%   Figure (SimBiologyTrellisPlot) with properties:
% 
%       Number: 2
%         Name: ''
%        Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
%     Position: [415 124 518 384]
%        Units: 'pixels'
% 
%   Show all properties
```

Using the parent handle, get the properties of its children

```
bx1 = bx.Children  

%   bx1 = 
% 
%   6x1 graphics array:
% 
%   Axes      (Group "group4")
%   Axes      (Group "group3")
%   Axes      (Group "group1")
%   Legend    (ValueY, ValueY)
%   Axes      (Group "group2")
%   Axes      (BackgroundAxes)
```

Now, you could see that there are 6 children (5 Axes and 1 legend) for bx handle. The properties of children could be manipulated as follows.

To get the list of parameters for each child, do

```
get(bx1(1))
%                        ALim: [0 1]
%                    ALimMode: 'auto'
%      ActivePositionProperty: 'position'
%           AmbientLightColor: [1 1 1]
%                BeingDeleted: 'off'
%                         Box: 'on'
%                    BoxStyle: 'back'
%                  BusyAction: 'queue'
%               ButtonDownFcn: {3x1 cell}
%                        CLim: [0 1]
%                    CLimMode: 'auto'
%              CameraPosition: [0.1359 0.0838 17.3205]
%          CameraPositionMode: 'auto'
%                CameraTarget: [0.1359 0.0838 0]
%            CameraTargetMode: 'auto'
%              CameraUpVector: [0 1 0]
%          CameraUpVectorMode: 'auto'
%             CameraViewAngle: 6.6086
%         CameraViewAngleMode: 'auto'
%                    Children: [2x1 Line]
%                    Clipping: 'on'
%               ClippingStyle: '3dbox'
%                       Color: [1 1 1]
%                  ColorOrder: [7x3 double]
%             ColorOrderIndex: 3
%                   CreateFcn: ''
%                CurrentPoint: [2x3 double]
%             DataAspectRatio: [2.2045 2.2974 1]
%         DataAspectRatioMode: 'auto'
%                   DeleteFcn: ''
%                   FontAngle: 'normal'
%                    FontName: 'Helvetica'
%                    FontSize: 8
%               FontSmoothing: 'on'
%                   FontUnits: 'points'
%                  FontWeight: 'normal'
%                   GridAlpha: 0.1500
%               GridAlphaMode: 'auto'
%                   GridColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
%               GridColorMode: 'auto'
%               GridLineStyle: '-'
%            HandleVisibility: 'on'
%                     HitTest: 'on'
%               Interruptible: 'on'
%     LabelFontSizeMultiplier: 1.1000
%                       Layer: 'bottom'
%              LineStyleOrder: '-'
%         LineStyleOrderIndex: 1
%                   LineWidth: 0.5000
%              MinorGridAlpha: 0.2500
%          MinorGridAlphaMode: 'auto'
%              MinorGridColor: [0.1000 0.1000 0.1000]
%          MinorGridLineStyle: ':'
%                    NextPlot: 'replace'
%               OuterPosition: [172.4400 6.7600 289.2000 211.0400]
%                      Parent: [1x1 Figure]
%               PickableParts: 'visible'
%          PlotBoxAspectRatio: [1 0.8046 0.8046]
%      PlotBoxAspectRatioMode: 'auto'
%                    Position: [239 49 174 140]
%                  Projection: 'orthographic'
%                    Selected: 'off'
%          SelectionHighlight: 'on'
%                  SortMethod: 'childorder'
%                         Tag: ''
%                     TickDir: 'in'
%                 TickDirMode: 'auto'
%        TickLabelInterpreter: 'tex'
%                  TickLength: [0.0100 0.0250]
%                  TightInset: [0 1.4852e-06 0 0]
%                       Title: [1x1 Text]
%     TitleFontSizeMultiplier: 1.1000
%             TitleFontWeight: 'bold'
%                        Type: 'axes'
%               UIContextMenu: []
%                       Units: 'pixels'
%                    UserData: []
%                        View: [0 90]
%                     Visible: 'on'
%               XAxisLocation: 'bottom'
%                      XColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
%                  XColorMode: 'auto'
%                        XDir: 'normal'
%                       XGrid: 'off'
%                      XLabel: [1x1 Text]
%                        XLim: [-2.0686 2.3405]
%                    XLimMode: 'manual'
%                  XMinorGrid: 'off'
%                  XMinorTick: 'off'
%                      XScale: 'linear'
%                       XTick: [-2 -1 0 1 2]
%                  XTickLabel: ''
%              XTickLabelMode: 'manual'
%          XTickLabelRotation: 0
%                   XTickMode: 'auto'
%               YAxisLocation: 'left'
%                      YColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
%                  YColorMode: 'auto'
%                        YDir: 'normal'
%                       YGrid: 'off'
%                      YLabel: [1x1 Text]
%                        YLim: [-2.2136 2.3813]
%                    YLimMode: 'manual'
%                  YMinorGrid: 'off'
%                  YMinorTick: 'off'
%                      YScale: 'linear'
%                       YTick: [-2 -1 0 1 2]
%                  YTickLabel: ''
%              YTickLabelMode: 'manual'
%          YTickLabelRotation: 0
%                   YTickMode: 'auto'
%                      ZColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
%                  ZColorMode: 'auto'
%                        ZDir: 'normal'
%                       ZGrid: 'off'
%                      ZLabel: [1x1 Text]
%                        ZLim: [-1 1]
%                    ZLimMode: 'auto'
%                  ZMinorGrid: 'off'
%                  ZMinorTick: 'off'
%                      ZScale: 'linear'
%                       ZTick: [-1 0 1]
%                  ZTickLabel: ''
%              ZTickLabelMode: 'auto'
%          ZTickLabelRotation: 0
%                   ZTickMode: 'auto'
```

To get the value of paramater of a child, do

```
get(bx1(1), 'ZGrid')

%ans = 
%
%off
```

To customize parameters of each child, do

```
set(bx1(1), 'ZGrid', 'on')
```

Customize properties of subplots, legend, and title

```
%subplot 4
bx1(1).Title.String = 'Group 4';
bx1(1).Title.Position = [0.1359, 2.6, 0];
bx1(1).Title.FontWeight = 'bold';

%subplot 3
bx1(2).Title.String = 'Group 3';
bx1(2).Title.Position = [0.1359, 2.6, 0];
bx1(2).Title.FontWeight = 'bold';

%subplot 1
bx1(3).Title.String = 'Group 1';
bx1(3).Title.Position = [0.1359, 2.6, 0];
bx1(3).Title.FontWeight = 'bold';

%legend text, box, and location
bx1(4).String = {'SubgroupA', 'SubgroupB'};
bx1(4).Position = [397.2451 185 109.7549 29.2715];
h =findobj('type', 'legend');
set(h, 'Box', 'off');

%subplot 2
bx1(5).Title.String = 'Group 2';
bx1(5).Title.Position = [0.1359, 2.6, 0];
bx1(5).Title.FontWeight = 'bold';

% Title location
set(bx1(6), 'Position', [30, 30, 390, 324]);
```

After evaluating the children handles, we see a final plot shown at the end of this solution.

Other properties of the figure can be also modified and if you look at the source code of sbiotrellis (`'edit sbiotrellis'`) or typing the plot object followed by a letter  and tab completion (`t2.u` ), you could get the list of properties or hidden properties that can be manipulated after rendering the plot.

properties

```
    hFig;
    nPlots;
    plots;
```

properties (Hidden)

```
    layoutObj;
    labelx           = '';
    labely           = '';
    plottitle        = '';
    legendnames      = {};
    plotLegend;
    rows;
    cols;
    titleFontSize    = 8;
    axisLimitSlack   = .05
    backgroundInsets = [30 30 30 30];
    foregroundInsets = [50 50 05 35];
```

Output:

R - Lattice - xyplot:

[image: Image from Lattice - xyplot]

Matlab - sbiotrellis:

[image]

Comment: Hi Satish. This is very useful. Just regarding the renaming of each individual plot, when entering the section:
    bx = gcf;
    bx1 = bx.Children;

I get the error: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Which is causing that the edits on the title of inidivual charts to not be reflected.

Comment: Try to capture gcf after you render trellis plot from the command line and see if you get the same error. I am not in front of my desk now. When I get back, I will post the output for each captures.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. I ran all the code before the bx = gcf; line, confirmed that the plot was displayed, and ran the remaining part of the code and I still get the same error. 
Also, I get an error on the last command regarding the title location given that the bx1 struct has five fields and the code is trying to index field 6. I get the error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions. (Not sure if this is related to the first error)